# How to convert existing media for direct play via Jellyfin or Plex?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert exisitng media for playback on Jellyfin (or Plex Like servers). The idea is to make sure the media is in the correct format for video and sound so there is NO transcoding.

I have tried a few things.

```
ffmpeg -y -i infile.mp4 -threads 4 -vcodec h264 -b:v 1200k -filter:v yadif -acodec aac -ab 128k outfile.mp4 

ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -acodec aac output.mp4

HandBrakeCLI -i infile.mp4 -o outfile.mp4 -e x264 -q 20 -B 160
```

But my lack of knowlede and skills with ffmpeg is limited.
From what i read the sound needs to be AAC and the video must be constant bit rate or something. But not sure.

Anyone with working scripts that can help?

Comment: The server doesn't care about how it is encoded. What you should care about is the device actually playing the media, it is their capabilities that actually matter.

Comment: What happened when you tried the commands given? What steps did you follow? What is your actual problem with them? I have a Plex server with (mostly) DVD and some Blu rays ripped directly from my own collection with zero transcoding. For the most part they just play without transcoding on laptops and PCs and generally the only problems are with some streaming sticks that have trouble with the blu rays. Changing the streaming stick to a FireTV 4K Max fixed any issues as those devices can play high bitrate video natively.

Comment: The point being that you need to find out what your problem actually is. Is it the bitrate? Is it the codec? When you are playing a video you should be able to go to the webpage for your sever (on a laptop or PC) and see what the server is transcoding to using the control panel in the top right corner. If it is keeping the codec the same then you need to potentially change the bitrate. If the codec does change then your player presumably wants you to use that codec and you have your hint there.

Comment: So most of my media just plays (any device web, android etc). But some of them want to transcode. And since this is running from a PI4 the video becomes staggered. I have been to plenty of forums on the topic. But not single one has clear answer. So now I am asking here. It might have something to do with the video bitrates not being the same, some might be higher so it wants to transcode or the video bit rate is too high. I guess I would have to ask: what is the optimal ffmpeg settings needed for proper any device playback?

Comment: In my attempts the file got a lot smaller and the quality was horrendous.

Comment: There are no settings that allow playback on "any" device. 4K video will be awful at 1200kbps (1.2Mbps) h.264, which is why blu ray discs operate at 30Mbps. You might find 5Mbps H.26**5** to be somewhat okay, but from experience what you are seeing is a problem with an underpowered server. You cannot guess every combination of media you might have to support for end devices so having a more powerful server can make a world of difference. If nothing else you can get Plex to transcode ahead of time while keeping the original quality video by clicking the "..." on a video and selecting "optimise"